# benchmarks in the UFBV category

Tags: z3

I am looking for benchmarks in the UFBV category. This category is not yet directly represented in the SMT competition.

Sure, most of the (A)UFLIA benchmarks can be easily changed to UFBV benchmarks, by changing uninterpreted sorts to bitvector sorts and integer arithmetic to bitvector arithmetic. A script for automating this will be also helpful for me.

Regards,
Aboubakr Achraf El Ghazi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the UFBV (and BV) benchmarks used in the paper "[Efficiently solving quantified bit-vector formulas](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/files/fmcad10.pdf)" at:

- http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/ufbv.zip
- http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/bv.zip

BTW, these benchmarks have been submitted to SMT-LIB. So, they will eventually be available in the SMT-LIB website.